# Why am I getting no route matches for a nested resource that outputs properly to rake routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, devise, nested-attributes

I'm using Devise. I'm updating a collection of Log Entries.

My routes look like:

```
  devise_for :users


  resources :users do
    resources :exercises do
      resources :log_entries
    end
  end
```

I also got a form to `Started PUT "/users/1/exercises/1/log_entries"`

I then got the following error:

```
Routing Error

No route matches [PUT] "/users/1/exercises/1/log_entries"
```

edit: I see what the issue may be. I'm trying to update a collection of log_entries. So it's hitting PUT instead of POST. I'm not sure how to solve this since Rails doesn't offer a way to PUT a collection.

Edit x2: The reason I'm trying to do this is because I currently have a form that does this:

```
        = semantic_form_for [current_user, ew.exercise] do |exercise|
```

Inside the form is a collection of log_entries. Let's say there's 5.

Now I update each log_entry or add more dynamically. They hit the exercise_controller and I'm forced to set the user_id in a hackish way, like this:

```
params[:exercise][:log_entries_attributes].each do |value|
  value[1].merge!(:user_id => current_user.id)
end
```

What I want to do is hit the log_entries controller so I don't have to do the above. What makes this tricky is going through the collection properly.

Comment: what path is generating that error?

Comment: I got a form to hit PUT "/users/1/exercises/1/log_entries"

I got this error now: "Routing Error

No route matches [PUT] "/users/1/exercises/1/log_entries"

Comment: if it's a new object, you want it to post, not put...put is for updating existing objects

Comment: It's actually existing objects. A collection of them... it may be a new one or a combination of old ones plus a new one. gist: https://gist.github.com/645232a6f8e23c6119f5

Comment: what is the code that throws the error?

Comment: Submitting the form hits the routing error (because it's trying to do put) but they're also existing objects. I manually typed the route so that's probably why, but I have no idea how else to get the log_entries to go through users so the user_id is set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you are missing

`new_user_exercise_log_entry(@user,@exercises)`

for nested resources you can't call plain `new_user_exercise_log_entry()`

=== update ===

:url => user_exercise_log_entries_path(current_user, ew.exercise)

should be

:url => user_exercise_path(current_user, ew.exercise)

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I got a new error now though. Thoughts? It's related to the `put`

Comment: I see what the issue may be. I'm trying to update a collection of log_entries. So it's hitting PUT instead of POST. I'm not sure how to solve this since Rails doesn't offer a way to PUT a collection.

Comment: try `form_for [@user, @exercises, LogEntry.new]`

Comment: all depends on what is in form_for ???? I'm not sure what are you calling there. If you want to edit model you have to use helper methods in same manner as above `user_exercise_log_entry(@user,@exercises,@log_entry)'

Comment: This is my form_for https://gist.github.com/645232a6f8e23c6119f5 I'm using https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/ for easy additions of nested models.

Comment: So that's basically what it is without the path. That hits the exercise controller. The problem with that is I have to do this in the exercise controller:


    params[:exercise][:log_entries_attributes].each do |value|
      value[1].merge!(:user_id => current_user.id)
    end

That feels dirty. So I thought it should go through the log_entries controller to properly set the user_id. Thoughts?

Comment: it is not dirty, its mass assignment :) check http://railscasts.com/episodes/237-dynamic-attr-accessible how to do it right way. Rails is not modeled to handle your way without reinventing whole logic by your self, btw, PUT, POST and DELETE on log_entries controller only handle one LogEntry, not a list

Comment: Thanks Milan. You know your shit. I appreciate your help. I'll follow you on Twitter :)

Comment: P.s do you know of any libraries/frameworks that exist that encourage updating multiple objects at once? Does anything solve that problem? It's pretty common, isn't it?

Comment: well you don't need it. to be more concrete to your problem, I wouldn't create log_entry controller at all. Maybe if you need it to view them all, but then don't nest it. Ryan Bates (railscasts) have several episodes on how quickly code mass assignment, and that is all what you need, since you can mass assign to one attribute of model, in your case exercise.log_entries in exercises controller. There is so many different scenarios which are different to yours so it's really hard making such gem in ruby to cover all those cases. At least Im not avare of it :)